# Submit form (contact form) that links with my SQL database and replaces the submission form with a message on the same page via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to create a submit form (contact form) that links with my SQL database and replaces the submission form with a message on the same page via AJAX. I've tried W3C schools and a couple of step by step guides but still struggling. So far, I've written the HTML for and Validation and connected to my SQL database. However, I'm not sure what steps to take next. I'm new to coding and not sure what to do next...

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "Telephone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>

<div id="form">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["register.php"])?>">
  <fieldset>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Phone: <input type="tel" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, email, phonenumber,comment)
VALUES ($name , $email ,$phone,$comment)";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

Where put you $comment , $name and others and also configure you database name, password and database table.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it simply like this:

Create an empty div before Form's fieldset:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-8 conForm">
        <h4>Shoot a message!</h4>
        **<div id="message"></div>**
        <form method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="cform" id="cform">
          <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" placeholder="Your name..." >
          <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 noMarr" placeholder="Your email..." >
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="" rows="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submitBnt" value="Send message">
          <div id="simple-msg"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

in PHP print message like this after email sent:

```
if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked, i think you are totally new in coding world.so that's why i write full code in one page. create a **.php** file and paste this code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateName() {
  var name = document.getElementById('contact-name').value;
  if(name.length == 0) {
    producePrompt('Name is required', 'name-error' , 'red')
    return false;  }
  if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/)) {
    producePrompt('First and last name, please.','name-error', 'red');
    return false;  }
  producePrompt('Valid', 'name-error', 'green');
  return true;}

function validatePhone() {
  var phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone').value;
    if(phone.length == 0) {
      producePrompt('Phone number is required.', 'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;    }
    if(phone.length != 10) {
      producePrompt('Include area code.', 'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;    }
    if(!phone.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
      producePrompt('Only digits, please.' ,'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;    }
    producePrompt('Valid', 'phone-error', 'green');
    return true;}

function validateEmail () {
  var email = document.getElementById('contact-email').value;
  if(email.length == 0) {
    producePrompt('Email Invalid','email-error', 'red');
    return false;  }
  if(!email.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-[0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
    producePrompt('Email Invalid', 'email-error', 'red');
    return false;  }
  producePrompt('Valid', 'email-error', 'green');
  return true;}

function validateMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById('contact-message').value;
  var required = 10;
  var left = required - message.length;
  if (left > 0) {
    producePrompt(left + ' more characters required','message-error','red');
    return false;  }
  producePrompt('Valid', 'message-error', 'green');
  return true;}

function validateForm() {
  if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail() || !validateMessage()) {
    jsShow('submit-error');
    producePrompt('Please fix errors to submit.', 'submit-error', 'red');
    setTimeout(function(){jsHide('submit-error');}, 2000);
      return false; }  else {  }
}

function jsShow(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; }

function jsHide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';}

function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
  document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;}
  </script>
</head>
<form action="" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="name"       placeholder="Enter your name.." onkeyup='validateName()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ex: 1231231234" onkeyup='validatePhone()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onkeyup='validateEmail()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
          </div>   

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for='contactMessage'>Your Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id='contact-message'  name='message'  placeholder="Enter a brief message" onkeyup='validateMessage()'></textarea>
            <span class='error-message' id='message-error'></span>
          </div>

        <button onclick='return validateForm()' name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
        <span class='success-message' id='submit-success'></span>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_POST['submit']))) {

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; //change this to your username
$password = ""; //change this to your database password
$dbname = "db"; //change this to your database name
$name    = "$_POST[name]";
$phone   = "$_POST[phone]";
$email   = "$_POST[email]";
$message = "$_POST[message]";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);} 
//insert data into table named guestbook
$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, email, phone, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$message')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br/><font color=green>Your Comment Successfully Sent</font>";
} else {
   echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error; }
$conn->close();} 
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In your DATABASE, create a database whatever you named but dont forget to change in php file $dbname = ""; and create table with these code:

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255),
email varchar(255),
phone varchar(255),
message varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```